# Unable to run DNS queries when response is bigger than 512 Bytes and truncated

Tags: linux, networking, permissions, dns, dig

Situation:

- Linux machine running in Azure
- looking for a public domain that returns 112 results
- the packet response size is 1905 bytes

Case 1:

- interrogating google DNS 8.8.8.8 - it returns un-truncated response. Everything is OK.

Case 2:

- interrogating Azure DNS 168.63.129.16 - it returns a truncated response and tries to switch to TCP, but it fails there, with error "unable to connect to server address". However, it works perfectly well if I run the interrogation with "sudo".

The problem can be reproduced all the time:

1. Without sudo:

   ```
   $ dig  aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net @8.8.8.8

   ; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net @8.8.8.8
   ;; global options: +cmd
   ;; Got answer:
   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49847
   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 112, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

   ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
   ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
   ;; QUESTION SECTION:
   ;aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net. IN   A

   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net. 119 IN CNAME  bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc.bidswitch.net.
   bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc.bidswitch.net. 119 IN CNAME bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net.
   bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.189.137
   bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.205.98
   --------
   bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.28.65
   bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.213.32

   ;; Query time: 12 msec
   ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
   ;; WHEN: Thu Oct 03 22:28:09 EEST 2019
   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 1905


   [azureuser@testserver~]$ dig  aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net
   ;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
   ;; Connection to 168.63.129.16#53(168.63.129.16) for aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitc                                                                                                                               h.net failed: timed out.
   ;; Connection to 168.63.129.16#53(168.63.129.16) for aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net failed: timed out.

   ; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net
   ;; global options: +cmd
   ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
   ;; Connection to 168.63.129.16#53(168.63.129.16) for aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net failed: timed out.
   ```
2. With sudo:

   ```
   [root@testserver ~]# dig  aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net
   ;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.

   ; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net
   ;; global options: +cmd
   ;; Got answer:
   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8941
   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 112, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

   ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
   ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1280
   ;; QUESTION SECTION:
   ;aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net. IN   A

   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net. 120 IN CNAME  bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc.bidswitch.net.
   bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc.bidswitch.net. 120 IN CNAME bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net.
   bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 60 IN A 35.211.56.153
   .......
   bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 60 IN A 35.207.61.237
   bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 60 IN A 35.207.23.245

   ;; Query time: 125 msec
   ;; SERVER: 168.63.129.16#53(168.63.129.16)
   ;; WHEN: Thu Oct 03 22:17:18 EEST 2019
   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 1905
   ```

I checked everything I found over internet, I saw nowhere an explanation why this works as intended only when ran from root account or with sudo permissions if the response package size is too big and the response gets truncated, forcing the DNS query to switch from UDP to TCP.

Adding "options edns0" or "options use-vc" or "options edns0 use-vc"  to /etc/resolv.conf doesn't help either.

Same behavior in CentOS 7.x, Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04

Update: tested with curl and telnet, the behavior is the same. Works with sudo or from root account, fails without sudo or from standard account.

Can anyone please provide some insight about why it needs superuser permissions when switching from UDP to TCP and help with some solution, if any?

UPDATE:

- I know this is long post, but please read it all before answering.
- Firewall is set to allow any to any.
- Port 53 is open on TCP and UDP in all the test environments I have.
- SELinux/AppArmor is disabled.

Update2:

Debian9 (kernel 4.19.0-0.bpo.5-cloud-amd64 ) works correctly without the sudo. 
RHEL8 (kernel 4.18.0-80.11.1.el8_0.x86_64) works correcly, but with huge delays (up to 30sec), without sudo.

Update3: 
List of distributions I was able to test and it doesn't work:

- RHEL 7.6, kernel 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64
- CentOS 7.6, kernel 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64
- Oracle7.6, kernel 4.14.35-1902.3.2.el7uek.x86_64
- Ubuntu14.04, kernel 3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64
- Ubuntu16.04, kernel 4.15.0-1057-azure
- Ubuntu18.04, kernel 5.0.0-1018-azure
- Ubuntu19.04, kernel 5.0.0-1014-azure
- SLES12-SP4, kernel 4.12.14-6.23-azure
- SLES15, kernel 4.12.14-5.30-azure

So, basically the only distribution I tested and is without problems is Debian 9. Since RHEL 8 has huge delays, which may trigger time outs, I cannot consider it fully working.

So far, the biggest difference between Debian 9 and the rest of distributions I tested is the systemd (missing on debian 9)... not sure how to check if this is the cause.

Thank you!

Comment: I whish I had the time to check "all the Internet" ;)o Using Cisco firewalls, by change? ASA?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - is not a networking issue, but a "permissions" issue from Linux side for the DNS mechanism, which seems to need "sudo" in order to switch from UDP queries to TCP queries.

Comment: That is not supposed to happen. Unless some util is using spoofing TCP packets, and then it is needing a setuid. Which command is it?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro basically every command you may think off, e.g. "telnet example.com 443" , "dig example.com" or "curl example.com"  . Running the same with sudo, works. As mentioned, the Linxu boxes in questions are default distributions from CentOS (7.7), Ubuntu(16.04 and 18.04) and I can confirm now the same for RedHat 7.6. I'll try to record this and post a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"***Can anyone please provide some insight about why this works like this and help with some solution, if any?***"

### SHORT ANSWER:

A default Azure VM is created with broken DNS: `systemd-resolved` needs further configuration. `sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved` will quickly confirm this. `/etc/resolv.conf` points to `127.0.0.53`- a local unconfigured stub resolver.

The local stub resolver `systemd-resolved` was unconfigured.  It had no forwarder set so after hitting `127.0.0.53` it had nobody else to ask.  Ugh.  Jump to the end to see how to configure it for Ubuntu 18.04.

If you care about how that conclusion was reached, then please read the Long Answer.

### LONG ANSWER:

### Why DNS Responses Truncated over 512 Bytes:

> TCP [RFC793] is always used for full zone transfers (using AXFR) and
> is often used for messages whose sizes exceed the DNS protocol's
> original 512-byte limit.

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7766

### ANALYSIS:

This was trickier than I thought.  So I spun-up an Ubuntu 18.04 VM in Azure so I could test from the vantage point of the OP:

My starting point was to validate nothing was choking-off the DNS queries:

```
sudo iptables -nvx -L
sudo apparmor_status
```

All chains in the ***iptables*** had their default policy set to **ACCEPT** and although ***Apparmor*** was set to "***enforcing***", it wasn't on anything involved with DNS. So no connectivity or permissions issues observed on the host at this point.

Next I needed to establish ***how*** the DNS queries were winding through the gears.

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 

# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search ns3yb2bs2fketavxxx3qaprsna.zx.internal.cloudapp.net
```

So according to `resolv.conf`, the system expects a local stub resolver called `systemd-resolved`. Checking the status of ***systemd-resolved*** per the hint given in the text above we see it's ***erroring***:

```
sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved

● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-10-08 12:41:38 UTC; 1h 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
 Main PID: 871 (systemd-resolve)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 441)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
           └─871 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Oct 08 12:42:14 test systemd-resolved[871]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
<Snipped repeated error entries>
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` set the order sources of sources used to resolved DNS queries.  What does this tell us?:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Well, the DNS queries will never hit the local `systemd-resolved` stub resolver as it's not specified in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Are the forwarders even set for the `systemd-resolved` stub resolver?!?!?  Let's review that configuration in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

```
[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

Nope: `systemd-resolved` has no forwarder set to ask if a local ip:name mapping is not found.

The net result of all this is:

- /etc/nsswitch.conf sends DNS queries to DNS if no local ***IP:name*** mapping found in `/etc/hosts`
- The DNS server to be queried is `127.0.0.53` and we just saw this is not configured from reviewing its' config file `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. With no forwarder specified in here, there's no way we'll successfully resolve anything.

### TESTING:

I tried to override the stub resolver `127.0.0.53` by directly specifying 168.63.129.16. This failed:

```
dig aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net 168.63.129.16

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.9-Ubuntu <<>> aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net 168.63.129.16
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 24224
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;168.63.129.16.         IN  A

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 08 13:26:07 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42
```

Nope: seeing `;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)` in the output tells us that we've not overridden it and the local, unconfigured stub resolver is still being used.

However using either of the following commands overrode the default `127.0.0.53` stub resolver and therefore succeeded in returning `NOERROR` results:

```
sudo dig aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net @168.63.129.16
```

or

```
dig +trace aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net @168.63.129.16
```

So any queries that relied on using the `systemd-resolved` stub resolver were doomed until it was configured.

### SOLUTION:

My initial- ***incorrect***- belief was that **TCP/53** was being blocked: the whole "***Truncated 512***" was a bit of a red-herring. The stub resolver was not configured. I made the assumption- I know, I know, "NEVER ASSUME ;-) - that DNS was otherwise configured.

### How to configure `systemd-resolved`:

### Ubuntu 18.04

Edit the `hosts` directive in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` as below by prepending `resolve` to set `systemd-resolved` as the first source of DNS resolution:

```
hosts:          resolve files dns
```

Edit the `DNS` directive (at a minimum) in`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`to specify your desired forwarder, which in this example would be:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=168.63.129.16
```

Restart `systemd-resolved`:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

### RHEL 8:

Red Hat almost does everything for you in respect to setting up `systemd-resolved` as a stub resolver, ***except they didn't tell the system to use it!***

Edit the `hosts` directive in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` as below by prepending `resolve` to set `systemd-resolved` as the first source of DNS resolution:

```
hosts:          resolve files dns
```

Then restart `systemd-resolved`:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

**Source**: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/config-rhel8-local-dns-caching-terrence-houlahan/

### CONCLUSION:

Once `systemd-resolved` was configured my test VM's DNS behaved in the expected way.  I think that about does it....

Comment: the DNS query works when ran from superuser account or with superuser permissions. As already mentioned in my problem description, the problem is unrelated to firewall. Also, the test machines are brand new Linux boxes, installed from default images available from their respective vendors, without any changes to users, permissions, etc.

Comment: @MarinNedea Your commands in the (2) examples are not exactly the same: you specified "8.8.8.8" in the first (non- sudo dig) but not in the second dig using sudo.  Looks like the resolver using sudo will come from the default system resolvers specified in /etc/resolv.conf.  My guess is that that the 8.8.8.8 is not allowed for TCP in the firewall-

Comment: that is just to show that google public DNS handles the DNS request differently, sending a 512 bytes response packet, which is actually an incomplete response, which however, allows the query to go further since it doesn't need to switch to TCP, as it would normally do when a big packet response is received. The other DNS server is 168.63.129.16 which is Azure Cloud default DNS ip. More on it: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/what-is-ip-address-168-63-129-16

Comment: please read again the problem description. Did you notice the "Firewall is set to allow any to any.
Port 53 is open on TCP and UDP in all the test environments I have.
SELinux/AppArmor is disabled." ?

Comment: @MarinNedea Hi bud- I spun-up an Azure VM to try to recreate you circumstances.  Pretty sure I figured out how things were 1/2 broken. Basically, any query that could override the default (unconfigured) stub-resolver was going to succeed and anything that could not was going to fail.

Comment: your solution works indeed in Ubuntu 18.04, but not in CentOS/RedHat and Ubuntu16.04. However, this is a great starting point for the investigation and hopefully we will get a  solution for the whole range of distributions. Accepting your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @MarinNedea I think I have notes on the systemd-resolved config for other distros.  Let me see if I can hunt them down and will post links to them to this answer.  Was great working with you on this problem Marin- very interesting!

Comment: for distributions that do not rely on systemd-resolved (resolveconf), I found the problem is also related to the glibc library: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=161181 . Looks like a fix is available in glibc2.3.90-9 .. the problem is trying to update this manually will most likely broke the system, as it  needs almost the whole system to be recompiled after installing the new version. ( broke my test machines several times trying). Somehow, on some systems, resolveconf manages to bypass this glibc issue, even with older glibc version, but not on all systems. Thank you!

Comment: @MarinNedea Looks like that bug report is old- reported in 2005 and closed in 2007-

Comment: I saw that, but the problem is the glibc version on most distributions today is still older than that version with the fix, and found no trace of a "backport". Also, because of glibc update implications, I do understand why no update was pushed yet by the major Linux Distribution vendors into their releases. Thinking that a faster way to solve this si have Azure modify the DNS responses to be only 512 byts long, like Google 8.8.8.8 does.

Comment: For those still looking for a solution on this, in case none of the above worked, please check https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent/issues/1673

Answer (score 1):

If someone see this thread and is having the same issue on an azure VM running linux, the error you are seeing is most probably related to the FW rules locally enforced/set by the Azure WAlinuxAgent.

Those rules restrict sending egress TCP packet to the upstream azure DNS server (168.63.129.16) on port 53 to the root user only. (Yes this is madness...)

`sudo iptables -L -t security`

**Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)**

| target | prot | opt | source | destination |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACCEPT | tcp | -- | anywhere | 168.63.129.16 | owner UID match root |
| DROP | tcp | -- | anywhere | 168.63.129.16 | ctstate INVALID,NEW |

CF: https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent/issues/1673

Answer (score 0):

First strange things: when requesting from 2 differents network connections (corporate network & personal dedicated server), i can't reproduce the truncation of answer:

```
$ dig +ignore aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net|more

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> +ignore aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53582
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 112, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net. IN   A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
aerserv-bc-us-east.bidswitch.net. 119 IN CNAME  bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc.bidswitch.
net.
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc.bidswitch.net. 119 IN CNAME bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multif
o.bidswitch.net.
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.198.80
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.28.65
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.21.156
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.55.252
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.212.159
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.70.114
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.143.99
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.0.44
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.205.98
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.50.47
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.40.174
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.7.162
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.118.20
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.190.79
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.54.244
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.54.230
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.60.30
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.5.194
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.97.53
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.192.26
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.80.22
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.37.223
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.38.49
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.61.237
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.70.45
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.56.153
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.196.219
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.12.175
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.131.33
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.117.99
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.23.245
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.21.191
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.155.238
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.166.124
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.225.231
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.82.120
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.13.126
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.46.230
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.29.109
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.201.160
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.52.158
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.239.215
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.247.128
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.180.252
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.160.123
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.73.85
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.3.121
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.166.205
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.163.92
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.241.92
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.150.67
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.49.200
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.148.225
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.165.199
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.190.56
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.177.221
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.130.95
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.18.234
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.59.8
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.190.86
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.212.197
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.124.105
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.249.122
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.166.163
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.255.194
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.69.212
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.51.91
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.97.73
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.119.122
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.214.84
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.75.175
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.60.160
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.51.125
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.175.225
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.78.105
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.123.219
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.230.248
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.119.133
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.241.216
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.145.178
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.182.35
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.87.230
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.236.194
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.236.230
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.189.137
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.52.29
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.139.113
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.225.15
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.230.178
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.123.196
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.154.229
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.175.142
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.17.175
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.155.208
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.213.32
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.109.194
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.25.234
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.130.94
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.248.106
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.210.111
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.223.18
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.125.62
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.204.171
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.180.174
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.29.9
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.45.75
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.172.232
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.207.31.235
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.137.11
bidcast-bcserver-gce-sc-multifo.bidswitch.net. 59 IN A 35.211.193.229

;; Query time: 833 msec
;; SERVER: 10.132.1.40#53(10.132.1.40)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 04 10:58:11 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 1905
```

Even when requesting Google's DNS (`dig @8.8.8.8`) i can't reproduce the behaviour you got.
So, i guess that the truncation is due to the nameserver you're using (@ 168.63.129.16)

The fact that the request, when fallbacking to TCP, failed under regular user but not as root looks more like a local issue.
Are you sure you don't have a firewall rule that forbid 53/TCP to normal users ?

Can you do the test with `dig @8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: the 1st point (Without sudo, in the problem descriptio) starts with the working result and uses @ 8.8.8.8. The firewall is disabled locally and the Azure Network Security rules are set to allow all traffic (any to any), on all ports and protocols.  The truncated package response from the DNS server is actually in conformity with RFC 2181, regarding the TC flag ( see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2181 ). So.. the problem seems to be Linux side..but I'm stuck here.. nothing in the logs .. Same happens on CentOS and Ubuntu, on new deployed VMs, without any customization.